# Wordpress looking for files in wrong directories

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress makes a lot of strange requests.

Here is strace output:

```
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/theme/yit/ilesystem_direct.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/core/yit/ilesystem_direct.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php", F_OK) = 0


access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wpseo-opengraph.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-opengraph.php", O_RDONLY) = 8

access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wpseo-replace-vars.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/class-wpseo-replace-vars.php", O_RDONLY) = 8

access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-yit-panel.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/theme/yit/Panel.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/core/yit/Panel.php", F_OK) = 0

access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/premium/", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wpseo-twitter.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/h/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-twitter.php", O_RDONLY) = 8
```

What is going on?

Comment: I also run to this. It's causing huge delay for my server, I suppose. Any idea?